# Cannot Assign Converted Value To Array

Tags: c++, arrays

I would like to assign the integer value which is included in a string to an array by reading file.

The code:

```
  #include<string>
  using namespace std;
  int main(){
    int s[10][10];
    ifstream trainfile;
    trainfile.open(trainname);
    if(!trainfile){
        cout<<"Cannot open file!"<<'\n';
        exit(1);
    }

   std::string line;    

   while (std::getline(trainfile, line))
   {       
       std::istringstream iss(line);          
       char z=line[0];
       s[0][0]=z-'0';              
   }
 }
```

Error:

```
  `Invalid types 'char[int]' for array subscript`
```

Comment: @Miki No reason to do that.

Comment: The edited code is still correct, either this isn't your code or you have a very broken compiler

Comment: @MattMcNabb You are right. My compiler is working wrongly because I ran the same code in a online site and it worked. What should I do?

Comment: check that the code you are looking at is actually the same code you are trying to compile (preferably invoke compiler from commandline). For example if you put some garbage in your code then check the compiler output changes. If it is really giving an error on this code then you'll have to get a new compiler

Comment: What type is `char[int]` even…

Answer (score 1):

The edited code works fine. I tried it using this online compiler http://www.tutorialspoint.com/compile_cpp_online.php

I tried printing `s[0][0]` using `cout` and it gives the output as expected

> 1

This was what i tried

```
#include<string>
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main(){
    std::string line;
    int s[10][10];
    line="1asd";
    char z=line[0];
    s[0][0]=z-'0';
    cout<<s[0][0];
}
```

The problem might be with your compiler.